# Performing ST_Within method in an SQL statement returns false although it shouldn't

Tags: postgis, sql, php

I have a POSTGIS database with a table "space" that has two columns "id" and "geometry".

I also have a PHP script that accesses the database and returns data. My program is running on mobile devices and delivers the id and a location. I now try to figure out if the table "space" does have an entry with the given id and if so, if the user is within the boundaries of the geometry in "geometry".

This is my code:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$lon = $_POST['lon'];
$lat = $_POST['lat'];

$statementCheck = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM space WHERE id= :id 
    AND ST_Within(ST_MakePoint($long, $lat), geometry)");
$statementCheck->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statementCheck->execute();
```

My problem is: `$statementCheck->execute()` returns false. However, I'm sure that there is a matching dataset in the table. Am I using ST_Within in a wrong way? The tutorials I looked at suggest that this is the way to do it. I'm a bit suspecting the ",geometry" part of ST_MakePoint to be not accurate.

edit: Fixed typing error.

Comment: Could you provide the values for `$long`, `$lat` and `geometry`?

Comment: $lon is a decimal coordinate (here: 12.40....) and so is $lat (here: 50.56....). I don't know how to display the geometry. The statement is "false" and does not give a geometry output. When I entered it in the database, I used a GeoJSON representation and uploaded it with `ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(...`. In the database, it's represented as a whole series of numbers...

Comment: It should not be a coordinate issue. Everything I handled was in EPSG 4326 from the beginning, and since my device is an Android phone, its location should also have matching coordinates.

Comment: You refer to $long and $lon in different places. Are you referring to the right variables? Try using consistent names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set the SRID of your ST_Makepoint to the same as your space.geometry:

```
$statementCheck = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM space WHERE id= :id 
    AND ST_Within(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($long, $lat),4326), geometry)");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't improve it. :/ But I see the point, since I'm doing the same thing when writing the geometry into the table at another point in the software.

Comment: Well I'm sorry. That actually did solve my problem. The one geometry I was working on was in a different EPSG than I assumed it to be :/. Thanks for your help and the ST_SetSRID hint!